# octave - optimize point plotting for visualization

Tags: optimization, octave

I want to visualize the sectors of a hard disk platter formatted with [Zone Bit Recording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_bit_recording), using a zoning formula I developed, by plotting a set of points.

## The model & equations

The disk platter is a ring of radii *R<sub>0</sub>* & *R<sub>1</sub>*, containing *N<sub>T</sub>* concentric tracks with pitch *W* (so *N<sub>T</sub>* = ⌊(*R<sub>1</sub>* - *R<sub>0</sub>*)/W⌋ and the radius of sector *N* *R<sub>N</sub>* = *R<sub>0</sub>* + *W***N*); the sectors are numbered outwards. The manufacturing process allows a minimum **radial** bit pitch *L<sub>B</sub>*, therefore a minimum **radial** sector pitch *L<sub>S</sub>* = 8**L<sub>B</sub>**(*S* + *E*) (consider *S* to be 512 bytes). Because *L<sub>S</sub>* doesn't necessarily divide *R<sub>0</sub>*, the minimum number of sectors (i.e. on the innermost track) is actually *N<sub>S0</sub>* = ⌊*R<sub>0</sub>*/*L<sub>S</sub>*⌋, therefore the actual minimum sector pitch is *L<sub>S0</sub>* = *R<sub>0</sub>*/*N<sub>S</sub>*.

The main idea is that, when going outwards, every certain number of tracks *N<sub>TZ</sub>*, the circumference becomes large enough to add a sector to the track and still keep the new bit pitch above the minimum. This is expressed as

*N<sub>TZ</sub>* = ⌈*L<sub>S0</sub>*/*W*⌉

This in turn allows calculating the number of zones *N<sub>Z</sub>* as

*N<sub>Z</sub>* = ⌈*N<sub>T</sub>*/*N<sub>TZ</sub>*⌉,

the zone of track *N* as

*Z*(*N*) = ⌊*N*/*N<sub>TZ</sub>*⌋,

the number of sectors on track *N* as

*N<sub>S</sub>*(*N*) = *N<sub>S0</sub>* + *Z*(*N*)

## The code

This section of the script is a fairly direct translation of the previous formulas into plotting:

```
hold on; axis("equal");
parfor z = 0:NZ
    NS = NS0 + z;
    G = 2*pi/NS:2*pi/NS:2*pi;
    R(1:NS) = [25 + W.*z.*TZ:W:25 + W.*TZ.*(z+1)];
    polar(G,R,'.r');
end
hold off;
```

It doesn't always return something in a polar graph, and sometimes Octave freezes/crashes on larger inputs.

My main problem is that I'm not familiar enough with matrices in Octave to optimize this (I cut my teeth on C and assembly), along with the fact that `R` and `G` must have the same number of elements. Initializing using `R(1:NF)` was already a huge leap of understanding for me. I'm sure Octave/Gnuplot is capable of handling the millions (potentially hundreds of millions) of points this script would generate, but telling it to do so in an efficient manner is beyond me.

[image: This is an example of what the result should look like.]

UPDATE: I realized the above code does not even work. Here is an updated version which generates reasonable output and doesn't crash on conservative inputs, but still doesn't produce the exact plot.

```
for z = 0:NZ
  NF = NFm + z;
  G(1:TZ,1:NF) = 2*pi*ones(TZ,1)*[1:NF]/NF;
  R(1:TZ,1:NF) = (25 + W*(z*TZ+[1:TZ]'))*ones(1,NF);
  polar(G,R,'.r');
  clear R G;
end
```

Comment: Related to your last point: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291609/346663

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks

Comment: No problem. Imgur is now OK, so I went ahead and edited in the image for you.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the code was right all along:

```
hold on; axis("equal");
for z = 0:NZ
    NF = NFm + z;
    G(1:TZ,1:NF) = 2*pi*ones(TZ,1)*[1:NF]/NF;
    R(1:TZ,1:NF) = 25 + W*(z*TZ+[1:TZ]'*ones(1,NF));
    polar(G,R,'.r');
    clear R G;
end
hold off;
```

Note the `hold on;` at the beginning. I ran the same script a few times assuming that the graph was being redrawn each time, resulting in the previous, erroneous results being drawn.

The code was also written by me after trying out the matrix operators and indexing by myself, and reading several (read: a lot of) sources.

Moral: you can never research too much.